# Meaning of "Stay until the room is blue"

Tags: meaning

Recently, I stumbled onto a quote

> Stay until the room is blue.

I am not sure what it means and I would like to know because googling didn't yield any answers. What is the origin of the quote, and what is it related to?

Comment: Can you provide context?  I think your question cannot be answered without context.

Comment: I'm quite surprised this question is both downvoted and closed. It just so happened I came across this phrase in a graveyard today, written on a note left on a grave. What kind of context is expected here? A quote is a quote, plenty of context there!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's part of some art by [Yoko Ono](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yoko_Ono).

> All my pieces are white because I think that white is the only colour that allows **imaginary colour** to be put on. In the Lisson Gallery I'm going to have a one room environment that's called 'The Blue Room Event'. The room is completely white and you're supposed to stay in the room until it becomes blue.

http://pers-www.wlv.ac.uk/~fa1871/yoko.html

> As the viewer reaches the final rooms of the show, one of the most ephemeral works empties the room of objects. Titled A Blue Room Event, phrases are written on the wall in a casual scrawl, describing the room the visitor inhabits. Instructing the visitor to “Stay until the room is blue[.]” [...] Both real and unreal, this room uses the most meager means to investigate the ways in which physical space is affected by **mental processes**.

http://www.artwrit.com/article/yoko-ono-at-the-serpentine-gallery-london/

So, it quite literally translates as: "Stay in this room until you [**imagine**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Imagine_(John_Lennon_song)) it being blue."

Comment: In spite of the fact that you've used the word *art* in the same sentence as *Yoko Ono*, this is an excellent answer. (And I saw what you did there with *imagine*). I hope the OP confirms the context, and in anticipation of that, you have my upvote.